# Integer Arguments Error

Tags: python, arguments, sys

I'm attempting to write a program that takes two integer arguments. After some research, I've learned that I need to use the `int()` funtion when defining the arguments. However, I get an error when I try this code:

```
import sys

a, b = int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2])
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-7a4a02a9d164> in <module>()
----> 1 a, b = int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2])

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-f'
```

I've been unable to resolve this despite researching. Is this an issue related to my python version perhaps?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'm running this code in a Jupyter Notebook. Running the same code in Terminal throws this error:

```
>>> import sys
>>> a = int(sys.argv[1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: How are you running your script?  The error shows that one of the arguments is `-f`, which can't be converted to an integer.

Comment: How are you running your python script?

Comment: I'm doing this interactively in a Jupyter Notebook. Is this not the proper way to be writing a program? @BrenBarn

Comment: Why are you using `sys.argv` in an interactive context?  `sys.argv` is for reading arguments passed on the command line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You haven't assigned argv to anything. Argv contains the command line arguements for a python script run from the shell. L[earn about argv here:](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm) Run in the terminal, argv will be an empty list with zero elements. So argv[0] and argv[1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm) can't be accessed (they don't exist).

When you run your script in a Jupityer notebook, the notebook itself has command-line arguments 'higher up'. Your first argument isn't what you want (whatever integer you entered), so you can't convert it's type.

You have three options for writing a program:
 - Work directly from a script
 - Command Line Arguments
 - input during runtime

You might not even need to use command line arguments.

```
def add_from_user_input():
    a = input('first number')
    b = input('second number')
    return a+b
```

Comment: Thanks for your very informative answer. I was unaware of the relationships you pointed out and am now on track to understanding this more fully. Much appreciated!